# Scala and Spark: Error while createStream

Tags: scala, spark-streaming

Error while : creating a stream of tweets in Spark using Scala and Twitter4j.
Below is snippet of my code:

```
scala> val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(10))
scala> val cb = new ConfigurationBuilder
scala>cb.setDebugEnabled(true).setOAuthConsumerKey("**********").setOAuthConsume
scala> val auth = new OAuthAuthorization(cb.build)
scala> val tweets = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc,auth)
```

> error: overloaded method value createStream with
>   alternatives:
>            (jssc: org.apache.spaark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext, twitterAuth: twitter4j.auth.Authorization)
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaReceiverInputDStream[twitter4j.Status]
>    (jssc:org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext,
>   filters:
>   Array[String])org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaReceiverInputDStream[twitter4j.Status]
>    (ssc:org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext,twitterAuth:
>   Option[twitter4j.auth.Authorization],filters:
>   Seq[String],storageLevel:
>   org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel)org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ReceiverInputDStream[twitter4j.Status]
>   cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext,
>   twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overload you're using [expects a `StreamingContext` and an `Option[Authorization]`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterUtils$), not an `Authorization`.

This should work:

```
val tweets = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, Some(auth))
```